# Property 'login' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any, any>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I am building login module in my app, For the first time i am using TypeScript so i dont know what to do with that problem.

I have an controller to handle login and User model, I'll paste my code down below.

In User model file i have static function to handle login stuff and my app is crashing.

I am getting error Property 'login' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any, any>

So if someone knows what's going on here please help me =]

```html
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express'
import ErrorHandler from '../app/Handlers/ErrorHandler';
import { User } from '../model/User';

export const signup_post = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let {email, password} = req.body
    try{
        const user = await User.create({
            email,
            password
        })
        res.status(201).json({ user: user.email });
    }
    catch(err){
        const errors = ErrorHandler.handleErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }
}

export const login_post = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let {email, password} = req.body
    try {
        const user = await User.login(email, password);
        user.save();
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        const errors = ErrorHandler.handleErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
      }
}
```

```html
import mongoose, { mongo } from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import validator from 'validator'

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter an email'],
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email'],
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter an password'],
        minlength: [6, 'Minimum password length is 6 characters']
    },
})

interface User {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}


userSchema.pre<User>('save', async function (next) {
    this.password = this.password + "1"
    next();
})

// static method to login user
userSchema.statics.login = async function(email, password) {
    const user = await this.findOne({ email });
    if(user) {
       const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
       if(auth) {
           return user;
       }
       throw Error('incorrect password')
    }
    throw Error('incorrect email');
}


export const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you should just describe your model using interface. E.g.:

```
// instead of 'interface User'
export interface UserDocument { 
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface UserModel extends mongoose.Model<UserDocument> {
  login(email: string, password: string): UserDocument;
}

...

const User: UserModel = mongoose.model<UserDocument, UserModel>("user", userSchema);
```